# Algorithm for mixed-effects models with 100 random effects

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme, covariance-matrix

I am wondering if there is any algorithm can estimate a mixed-effects model with 100 random effects, i.e., the covariance matrix $\boldsymbol D$ for random effects is 100$\times$100.

I tried the following two:

- `lmer` in package `lme4` seems to run forever.
- package `lmm` runs one iteration and throws a warning message `Value of psi became non-pos.def. during iterations`. My understanding is that it just returns the starting values and the covariance matrix $\boldsymbol D$ is non-positive-definite.

There is a paper by [Ibrahim et al. (2011)](http://www.bios.unc.edu/research/bias/documents/Archive/Publishedpaper2/Biometrics2011.pdf) dealt with this issue. They employ the cholesky decomposition and shrink the non-zero elements row by row "to preserve
the positive definite constraint on $\boldsymbol D$".

How about if the variances for random effects are all non-zero? That is, we at least need to estimate 100 variances, this is still a great computation burden, am I right?

Any suggestions would be welcome! Thanks!